# Trying to add text to the value of a button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a text that I send from the previous page to the value of a button, so the button has the sent value and the prior value added together. I store the value in session Storage just for context.

Example before page load:

```html
<input type="button" id="reset" value="You have completed ">
```

After page load - added text is "the laundry":

```html
<input type="button" id="reset" value="You have completed the laundry">
```

Basically what I tried didn't put the text within the button:

```html
<input type="button" id="reset" value="Complete"><label><p id="result"></p></label>
<script>
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("currentAddress");
</script>
```

Comment: sessionStorage expired after each reload, you should use localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an input, you must use the .value property to set the button text:

```
document.getElementById("result").value = sessionStorage.getItem("chore");
```

And to append to an existent text:

```
document.getElementById("result").value += sessionStorage.getItem("chore");
```

Also, You can set up the text like in this example:

```
document.getElementById("result").value = "You have completed " + sessionStorage.getItem("chore");
```

Note: If you use an HTML button `<button >Content</button>` instead, you can use innerHTML to set the button text.

Comment: right so would I go about concatenating the current value with the previous one?

Comment: I added additional examples. You can append or set a new value concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

- you should use `value`, not `innerHTML`.
- and use `+=` to append the value to old value, not replace it
- if you want to replace, just use `=`
- plus you should use localStorage

  document.getElementById("result").value += localStorage.getItem("chore");